# Erro ao publicar site asp.net mvc 4

Tags: iis, asp.net-mvc-4

Ao publicar o site no iis 7.5, este erro ocorre ao tentar abrir o site:

> Multiple types were found that match the controller named 'Home'. This
>   can happen if the route that services this request
>   ('{controller}/{action}/{id}') does not specify namespaces to search
>   for a controller that matches the request. If this is the case,
>   register this route by calling an overload of the 'MapRoute' method
>   that takes a 'namespaces' parameter.

Como resolver ?

Código RouteConfig:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }

Código Controller:

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Controle de documentos";
}
@section featured {
    <section class="featured">
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <hgroup class="title">
                <h1>@ViewBag.Title.</h1>
                <!--<h2>@*ViewBag.Message*@</h2>-->
            </hgroup>
            <p>
                Este módulo foi desenvolvido para o envio e controle de documentos do portal.
            </p>
            <p>
                @if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    @Html.ActionLink("Calendário de documentos", "Index", "CalendarioAlertaSMS");
                }
                else{
                    @Html.ActionLink("Logar", "LogOn", "Conta");
                }

            </p>
        </div>
    </section>
}
```

Comment: Esse código que você postou é da view... na pasta controller, deve ter um arquivo chamado homeController.cs.

Answer (score 1):

Você deve estar com vários controllers chamados `Home`, ou separou o controlador em classes parciais mas em `namespaces` diferentes.

Mude o nome de um dos `controllers`, ou mude o `namespace` para que fiquem no mesmo `namespace`.

O erro que você encontrou é porque a plataforma encontra dois (ou mais) controladores chamados `Home`. Como ele não tem como distinguir, retorna o erro.

Comment: tenho só um controller chamado Home, estranho esse erro.

Comment: Coloque o código do controller... estranho mesmo. Coloque também o código do seu **routing**

Comment: Pronto @RSinohara.

Answer (score 1):

Este erro acontece quando existe mais de um Controller com o mesmo nome. Se você usar o recurso de Areas no MVC automaticamente é criado um Controller Home na nova área e isso já pode fazer com que este erro aconteça.

Para que o framework consiga configurar as rotas corretamente neste caso, os Controllers que possuem o mesmo nome devem estar em namespaces diferentes e você deve colocar o namespace no RouteConfig.cs como no exemplo abaixo.

```
namespace SeuProjeto
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

             routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                namespaces: new string[] { "SeuProjeto.Controllers" }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Caso você esteja usando Areas, dentro da Pasta Areas/NomeDaAreaCriada/
é criado automaticamente um arquivo NomeDaAreaCriadaAreaRegistration.cs. Onde são configuradas as rotas para esta área. É sempre recomendado colocar o namespace na criação destas rotas também.

```
namespace SeuProjeto.Areas.SuaArea
{
        public class SuaAreaAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration 
        {
            public override string AreaName 
            {
                get 
                {
                    return "SuaArea";
                }
            }

            public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
            {
                context.MapRoute(
                    "SuaArea_default",
                    "SuaArea/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                    namespaces: new string[] { "SeuProjeto.Areas.SuaArea.Controllers" }
                );
            }
        }
    }
```

Esta linha é a que vai resolver o seu problema => `namespaces: new string[] { "namespace do seu controller" }`